# How do I create subtotals with EPPlus

Tags: epplus

I have developed using Excel InterOp in the past and could easily recreate the Data->SubTotal functionality of Excel by simply using Range.Subtotal. I can't seem to find any examples of the same functionality in EPPlus. The only option I saw was looping through the data and inserting subtotal functions at the appropriate rows. I would prefer to leverage the cells.loadfromcollection() functionality in EPPlus and then insert the subtotals like I can with Excel Interop. Is this possible?

Comment: Might want to post some code - you are more likely to get a response.  Can you create a `Table`?  If so, you could set `ShowTotal` to true like in their sample: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleApp.Core/Sample9.cs#L94

Comment: I can create a table and get showtotal, but that doesn't give me the functionality of the Range Subtotal from Excel InterOp. That gives you one total for the entire column, I want subtotals in the column based on the value of another column.